# Can page size be set with dynamodb.ScanPages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

The documentation for working with dynamodb scans, [found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination), makes reference to a `page-size` parameter for the AWS CLI.

In looking at the documentation for the go AWS SDK, [found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.Scan), there is function ScanPages.  There is an example of how to use the function, but no where in the documentation is there a way to specify something like `page-size` as the AWS CLI has.  I can't determine how the paging occurs other than assuming if the results exceed 1MB, then that would be considered a page based on the go documentation and the general scan documentation.

I'm also aware of the `Limit` value that can be set on the `ScanInput`, but the documentation indicates that value would function as a page size only if every item processed matched the filter expression of the scan:

> The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching items)

Is there a way to set something equivalent to `page-size` with the go SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How Pagination Works in AWS?**

> DynamoDB paginates the results from Scan operations. With pagination,
> the Scan results are divided into "pages" of data that are 1 MB in
> size (or less). An application can process the first page of results,
> then the second page, and so on.

So for each request if you have more items in the result you will always get the `LastEvaluatedKey`. You will have re-issue scan request using this `LastEvaluatedKey` to get the complete result.

For example for a sample query you have `400` results and each result fetches to the upper limit `100` results, you will have to re-issue the scan request till the `lastEvaluatedKey` is returned empty. You will do something like below. [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination)

```golang
var result *ScanOutput
for{
    if(len(resultLastEvaluatedKey) == 0){
         break;
    }
    input := & ScanInput{ 
        ExclusiveStartKey= LastEvaluatedKey
        // Copying all parameters of original scanInput request
    }
    output = dynamoClient.Scan(input)
}
```

**What page-size on AWS-CLI does?**

The scan operation scan's all the dynamoDB and returns result according to filter. Ordinarily, the AWS CLI handles pagination automatically.The AWS CLI keeps on re-issuing scan request for us. This request and response pattern continues, until the final response.

The `page-size` tells specifically to scan only the `page-size` number of rows in the DB table at a time and filter on those. If the complete table is not scanned or the result is more than `1MB` the result will send out `lastEvaluatedKey` and cli will re-issue the request.

Here is a sample request response from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination).

```
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name Movies \
    --projection-expression "title" \
    --filter-expression 'contains(info.genres,:gen)' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":gen":{"S":"Sci-Fi"}}' \
    --page-size 100  \
    --debug
```

```
b'{"Count":7,"Items":[{"title":{"S":"Monster on the Campus"}},{"title":{"S":"+1"}},
{"title":{"S":"100 Degrees Below Zero"}},{"title":{"S":"About Time"}},{"title":{"S":"After Earth"}},
{"title":{"S":"Age of Dinosaurs"}},{"title":{"S":"Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs 2"}}],
"LastEvaluatedKey":{"year":{"N":"2013"},"title":{"S":"Curse of Chucky"}},"ScannedCount":100}'
```

We can clearly see that the `scannedCount:100` and the filtered count `Count:7`, so out of 100 items scanned only 7 items are filtered. [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Count)

**From Limit's [Documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/v1.40.16/service/dynamodb/api.go#L18779-L19017)**

```golang
    // The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching
    // items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the limit while processing
    // the results, it stops the operation and returns the matching values up to
    // that point, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to apply in a subsequent operation,
    // so that you can pick up where you left off.
```

So basically, `page-size` and `limit` are same. `Limit` will limit the number of rows to scan in one Scan request.