# How to limit the number of items returned in a single page of DynamoDB result

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I am using `Pagination` with the latest `DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient`.

However while applying the limit() on the `QueryEnhancedRequest` its not limiting the items on a single page. Example: if I pass `limit(1)` still its showing 2 records in the `result`. Not sure if the `limit()` takes number of items as the parameter or the number of pages. If its pages, is there any way to limit the number of `items` per page? We know that DDB creates pages with max size of 1MB. but our json records have size in bytes, which means that `1000s` of records will be fetched per page. Isn't this inefficient? Is it possible to limit the `items` per page?

Comment: Can you please add some demo code?

Comment: You can typically [supply an item limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Limit) when using Query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit method in QueryEnhancedRequest for DynamoDB Java v2 sdk doesn't limit as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417472/limit-method-in-queryenhancedrequest-for-dynamodb-java-v2-sdk-doesnt-limit-as-e)

Comment: The decision to use limit as the option name, while it does not actually match what limit typically does across other AWS SDKs, is very weird and confusing. But the above question should answer your question 

Comment: Actually, that client does not actually seem to limit the item fetched via the API but just using Java methods... I'd just go with the normal async client. The enhanced client is really for creating/modifying tables not dealing with data tbh.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary thanks a lot!!! My usecase involves querying using GSI and pagination. Do you suggest switching to the other DynamoAsyncClient for the same? What are your views

Comment: @ghostrider yes I would recommend switching. This client is enhanced only for some use cases.

Comment: The enhanced client is quite verbose and confusing. I hope the usual async client is comparatively easy for indexes and pagination

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it is not limiting the number items in the results.

The documentation says:
*Note:The **limit does not refer to the number of items to return**, but how many items the database should evaluate while executing the query. Use limit together with Page.lastEvaluatedKey() and exclusiveStartKey in subsequent query calls to evaluate limit items per call.*
[Here is the link](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/model/QueryEnhancedRequest.Builder.html#limit-java.lang.Integer-)

Comment: So limit(1) should evaluate 1 item and return at most 1 item, but that does not match what the OP is saying. I think we need to see the OP's code here.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! My usecase involves querying using GSI and pagination. Do you suggest switching to the other DynamoAsyncClient for the same? What are your views